# How can I stop ToolTips from inheriting my TextBlock style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tooltip, textblock

I've defined a style within my application resources that I want all of my textblocks to inerit :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="1" ShadowDepth="0" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
</Style>
```

I don't want to have to go through and explicitly dictate the style on each textblock - I just want all of them to inherit this style naturally.

Unfortunately, when I define a tooltip, that tooltip also picks up this style. I'm guessing it's because the thing incorporates a `TextBlock` somewhere in it's design.

What I AM okay with is having to go through and style each defined tooltip ( since they are used less ubiquitously throughout my application ), so if there's some way to define a tooltip style that will override the inherited textblock style, I'm fine with that.

So, what can I do to stop my tooltips from inheriting the TextBlock style?

Comment: It's a terrible idea to set a global default style on `TextBlock`, and this is why. Set the default `TextBlock` style only where it's needed, not universally. Consider using `Label` instead of `TextBlock` for the styled text instances. You can style the padding/margin etc. to make it look exactly the way you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a terrible idea to set a global implicit style on `TextBlock`, and this is why. `TextBlock` is the primitive that displays text. It's much better to set the implicit `TextBlock` style only where it's needed, not universally.

Or consider using `Label` instead of `TextBlock` for the styled text instances, and have an implicit `Label` style. That's one reason why `Label` exists. You can style the padding/margin etc. to make it look exactly the way you want.