# How can I stop a WPF control inheriting an effect from its parent?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I have a WPF UserControl with many child controls. The root control is a Grid.  I have a need to apply a BlurEffect to all the controls if a button within the control is clicked.  I have solved this using a style on the main grid which is activated through databinding.

```
<Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBlurred, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <BlurEffect Radius="75" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

And the button that triggers it:

```
<Button x:Name="btnBlur" Style="{StaticResource ScanButton}" Margin="30,0,0,0" Width="150" Command="{Binding BlurCommand}">
    <TextBlock Text="Blur" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
</Button>
```

My issue is that the blur button itself also has the blur effect applied, because it is a child element within the entire grid.  The button also already has a style applied to it, which affects other buttons on the same control.

Is there a way to prevent the blur effect from being applied on this single button while still having it applied on all other child components of the grid?

**Update:** I am using an MVVM pattern for the application, and my ViewModel knows absolutely nothing about the view itself, so I cannot reference the particular button through code.  Ideally, I would like a way to not apply or "unapply" the blur effect just to that particular button.

I have attempted to add the same style trigger to my button, and set the Effect property to null when databinding is triggered.  This does not work, and it seems the root grid's effect overrides anything done at the child control level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override application styles in a wpf control created at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788203/how-to-override-application-styles-in-a-wpf-control-created-at-runtime)

Comment: You cannot partially inherit a style. If you don't want to inherit the style, then set the style to something else, either `null` or another style. See proposed duplicate, as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369839/how-can-i-stop-tooltips-from-inheriting-my-textblock-style, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079342/stop-child-from-inheriting-parent-style-in-tabcontrols, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660422/how-to-stop-inherit-from-style-and-change-the-background-color-of-textbox, etc.

Comment: Just don't apply the effect to the whole grid and apply it to a nested parent panel that doesn't include your button....unless I'm misinterpreting your intent that is.

Comment: There are many nested parent panels within this particular control - lots of buttons, borders, other containers with more controls.  I was hoping for a way to apply the effect once, and perhaps "unapply" the effect on the particular button (or other control) that I don't want it applied.

Comment: Right, so put all those in their own panel and apply your blur to it as the parent of the elements that actually require the effect? Otherwise it's behaving as expected and as long as your button is a child it will receive the effect as well.

Comment: That's the same as saying "pull the button out of nested controls where it's located so it doesn't have the effect applied".  I don't believe that will work, as it will mess with the layout of that button (i.e. margins to nearby buttons and controls, overall location, etc.)

Comment: There is no setting that avoids applying effects to a child control. Hence if you want to avoid blur on that button you need it to not be a child of where the effect is applied. That is your one option. If it's a child of a blurred parent it will be blurred. As a work round you could perhaps put  rectangle or something where your button is now. Put the button in the adorner layer and associate with that rectangle for size and position.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments posted, it seems there is no way to override or avoid the blur effect on a child control.

As a solution, I just copied-pasta'd the data trigger code to all the different parent containers and controls so that it wouldn't affect the particular button.  It's certainly not elegant, as the same trigger code appears multiple times throughout the Xaml.

I am unsure if I can put the code into a separate style and still reference/use the databinding that triggers the effect, but it's perhaps something I will attempt when I have more time.  For now, as ugly as the solution is, it works.

Comment: An adorner would be a more elegant solution. Since this is rendered in the separate adorner layer, it "escapes" out the container the child control is in.  The reason blur works like this is because it's a weighted average bitmap effect. Gaussian blur literally iterates the pixels and applies a weighted average to each using values out that pixel and those surrounding it.  https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-is-gaussian-blur-implemented

Comment: Thanks, Andy.  I may try it, though from the microsoft documentation, adorners cannot be bound via xaml as of yet, so it would have to be some type of code-behind solution.  I was hoping to keep everything xaml based, but this may be a better solution.

Comment: Coding adorners is not trivial. But this is a problem people already noticed and wrote code to make the task easier https://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/07/12/wpf-adorners-part-4-ndash-simple-and-powerful-system-for.aspx